# React does not re-render all componenets on state update in a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've created 2 components `C1` and `C2` and one `custom hook` useCounter.

`C1` displays `"count"` property of `useCounter hook`.

`C2` displays `"count"` property and also increment or decrement it on button click.

`Current behavior:` When the `"count"` is changed, the updated value is displayed only in `C2` and not in `C1`.

`Expected behavior:` Both components should `re-render` on the `"count"` update.

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

`PS:` I've already done this using `Context API` and `redux`. Just want to know if the same behavior could be achieved using `custom hooks` :)

`Codesandbox link:` [Custom hooks demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-shockley-e9fb4)

```
import { useState } from "react";

function useCounter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const updateCounter = newVal => {
    setCount(newVal);
  };

  //return [count, useCallback( (newVal) => setCount(newVal))];
  return [count, updateCounter];
}
export default useCounter;
```

Comment: unless you wrap these inside a parent container that uses the custom hooks they won't be sharing the state

Comment: If you want them to share state, then make your custom hook a context. Hooks are just functions. They don't have "shared state", just like a function's state doesn't get shared between calls. For example, if a hook shared its state, then you would only be able to use the "useState" hook once, because that state object would be shared throughout your entire app. That doesnt make sense. Hooks are instances. Every time you call one, it is a new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Do two components using the same Hook share state?** No. Custom Hooks are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic (such as setting up a subscription and remembering the current value), but every time you use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully isolated.

Refer point #3 in [Using a Custom Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook)

---

> They’re not a way to share state — but a way to share stateful logic. We don’t want to break the top-down data flow!

Reference: [Making Sense of React Hooks](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/making-sense-of-react-hooks-fdbde8803889)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use Context API to share the same instance, as the custom hook `useCounter` will assign a new instance of `count` on mount:

```
export const CounterContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const counterController = useCounter();
  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={counterController}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>App Component</h1>
        <hr />
        <C1 />
        <hr />
        <C2 />
      </div>
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
}

// Use context
function C1() {
  const [count] = useContext(CounterContext);
  return (
    <div>
      Component 1 <br />
      Count: {count}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit nostalgic-hypatia-by6s4]

---

Additionally, you can use a library like [`reusable`](https://github.com/reusablejs/reusable):

```
const useCounter = createStore(() => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return {
    counter,
    increment: () => setCounter(prev => prev + 1)
  }
});

const Comp1 = () => {
  const something = useCounter();
}

const Comp2 = () => {
  const something = useCounter(); // same something
}
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, thank for your reply :) but as I mentioned, I've already achieved this behavior using context and redux . I'm just trying to get this working with hooks.

Comment: Oh, so you have to "lift the state up" to the nearest common parent (App) in order to make it work only with custom hook.

Comment: Yes, that will work but I want direct sharing of the state (same as context or redux). also in official docs, they have used a state in two components. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook

Comment: Check out the updated answer, there is no such built-in API in react, but you can use a library or write it yourself (using CONTEXT).

Answer (score 1):

Hey I am totally agree with @RVRJ's explanations. So what happens when you import any hooks it will create new object of that hook. Let's suppose if you import same hook in two different files that means you are creating two difference object of that hook.

Here I have tried to solve your problem using hooks only, but I am importing hook only once and passed its object to child component `<C1 /> and <C2 />`.

Here is example how I created single object of **useCounter** hook

```
import React from "react";
import C1 from "./components/C1";
import C2 from "./components/C2";
import useCounter from "./hooks/useCounter";

function App() {
  const [count, updateCount] = useCounter(); // <<-- created one object

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>App Component</h1>
      <hr />
      <C1 count={count} updateCount={updateCount} /> {/* passing values ad props */}
      <hr />
      <C2 count={count} updateCount={updateCount} /> {/* passing values ad props */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and now you can access **count** and **updateCount** as props in every child.

*Here is C1 component after change*

```
// C1 component

 import React from "react";

 function C1({ count }) { {/* <-- access count as props */}
   return (
     <div>
       Component 1 <br />
       Count: {count}
     </div>
   );
 }
 export default C1;
```

*And here is your C2 component*

```
// C2 component
import React from "react";

function C3({ count, updateCount }) { {/* <-- access count and as updateCount props */}
  const handleIncr = () => {
    updateCount(count + 1);
  };
  const handleDecr = () => {
    updateCount(count - 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Component 2 <br />
      <button onClick={handleIncr}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={handleDecr}>Decrement</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      Count: {count}
    </div>
  );
}
export default C3;
```

Here is updated and working solutions of your problem https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-fire-b3exw

*Note: I don't know what is use case of using hooks for same state values, so I still recommend you should use **redux** for sharing states between components.*